# SearchView (support-v7) with additional icons - wrong width after changing fragment and return to it

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I use the SearchView inside a fragment. In the right of the SearchView I have two other icons. See main.xml (menu layout).

main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:mContext=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mi_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/actionProductSearch"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/mi_scanner"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_barcode"
    android:title="@string/actionProductScan"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/mi_basket"
    android:title="@string/actionShoppingcart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_shopping_cart"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

At the first start it looks verv good. When write somthing into the SearchView, it looks already good. When I switch to another fragment during the SearchView is expanded and I return then to the old fragment and enabling the search mode with `MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(menuItemSearch)` the two icons are only shown as menu. [SearchView problem with expanding by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX8Ut.png).

Even when I change `showAsAction` to `always` its the same problem.

Have someone a similar problems or knows how I solve it?

Comment: have you implemented prepareOptionMenu method in main acitivity?

Comment: @pankaj khedekar No, I don't. Should you give me a hint, what I do there?